# how to fix the text size dynamically for different screen resolutions on android

Tags: android, layout

i have  a home screen with header and footer and in between i have ten rows of text to display. the text size is hard coded in java but when i run the app the footer gets stretched to adjust with the text size fixed. but it looks odd when it gets stretched. is there a way to assign the text size dynamically based on the screen. please help me with this, if you could look at the image you will understand the footer problem.

```
if (dpiClassification == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
        if (isTablet) {
            textSize = (int) (((d.getHeight() - (totImageHeight)) / 10) - (25 * dm.density));
        } else {
            textSize = (int) (((d.getHeight() - (totImageHeight)) / 10) - (11 * dm.density));
        }

    } else if (dpiClassification == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
        if (isTablet) {
            textSize = 90;// (int) (((d.getHeight() - (totImageHeight)) /
                            // 10) - (15 * dm.density));
        } else {
            textSize = (int) (((d.getHeight() - (totImageHeight)) / 10));
        }
    } else {
        textSize = (int) (((d.getHeight() - (totImageHeight)) / 10));
    }
```

Comment: Try using sp units instead of px for text sizes.

Comment: @Pink By any chance are you the same [person as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/991423/pink-candy)?

Comment: yes reno, i was not able to access that account for some reason, thats why created a new account. sorry

Comment: That's ok, I've got those accounts merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set your text size in DP and dynamically convert DP to PX and put this PX values in

```
*.textSize(pxValue);
```

To convert I use next Code:

```
private static DisplayMetrics metrics = null;
private static float density = 0.0;

private int dpToPxConverter(Context context, int dp){
        if (metrics == null) {
            metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            density = metrics.density;
        }
        return (int) (density * dp + 0.5f);
    }
```

Hope it help you!